# Why to mutate Redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

I had a job interview question and I was asked:

> When would we want to mutate the Redux's store state?

Normally, you return a new instance of the state of the store instead of mutating it. Assume that React JS is out of the picture and we use a different UI library where `shouldComponentUpdate()` is not in the equation.

I couldn't answer the question and I would like the help from the community in case the same question pops up. Thanks!

Comment: You don't mutate redux state, that's the whole idea of redux.

Comment: Yeah to clarify, when you say "mutate" do you mean through actions/reducers, or through direct property mutation (e.g. getStore().foo.bar = 25)?

Comment: We mutate it in the reducer where we return the state after an action is complete.

Comment: @JediahDizon "We mutate it in the reducer where we return the state" --- you don't mutate it, you replace it with an entirely new state.

Comment: I assume they are talking about mutating the original state and then returning it within the reducer, instead of doing a shallow copy/spread first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a trick question, because the answer is ***never***.

Please see the [Redux FAQ section on immutability](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data) for more details.